# Get the uid of logged in user in firebase using python

Tags: python, firebase, uid

I want to get the image that a user uploads to storage by logging into firebase from android app. For that I need the uid of that current user. How do I do that? I can get list of all users in firebase. And I can also get uid of user, but which is in alphabetical order. I need the current uid of user.